# Which platform is meant by "Browser"?

Tags: c#, .net, platform

In the .NET code for the HttpClient class I found this attribute: `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]`
So, several fields are not supported by the "browser" platform, but which platform would this be? WebAssembly? Windows? Anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's when your code runs *within* a browser. Right now that's Blazor WebAssembly (not Blazor Server, as the code actually runs on a server).

Comment: can you explain *why* httpclient won't work in Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: You can use HttpClient in WebAssembly, just not [all the methods](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/de0b85f2b1690355f05bf13d3a88b8828b9853b1/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L453-L465), due to how browser isolation works. I my use of Blazor WebAssembly, I haven't noticed any differences in how HttpClient functions.

Comment: Because in the browser you can map many http client abstractions onto the javascript fetch api. But the javascript sandbox doesn't expose everything that a raw socket client can access.